# Split a file into a test file and a training file using Weka

Tags: java, command-line, weka

I found the following code, which distributes the examples as 75% training and 25% test data:

```
java weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds -i full.arff -o train.arff -c last -N 4 -F 1 -V
java weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds -i full.arff -o test.arff -c last -N 4 -F 1
```

But, I need to split the data such that 70% are used to train and 30% are used for testing.

How do I do this?

I don't want the split to be randomized.

Comment: What do you mean by "split to be randomized?"

Comment: The feature vectors should not be rearranged in a random order before splitting

Answer (score 0):

Based on their [JavaDoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/filters/supervised/instance/StratifiedRemoveFolds.html), one possibility, albeit a little clunky, would be to use `10` folds and then merge 3 pieces together for test and merge 7 pieces together for training.

```
java weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds -i full.arff -o piece1.arff -N 10 -F 1    
java weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds -i full.arff -o piece2.arff -N 10 -F 2
...
java weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds -i full.arff -o piece10.arff -N 10 -F 10
```

**Merging** to build test set:

```
java weka.core.Instances append piece1.arff piece2.arff > temp.arff
java weka.core.Instances append temp.arff piece3.arff > test.arff
```

The documentation for merging is [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html#main%28java.lang.String).

You could of course do the above steps in a `for` loop on the command line, but I am not sure which platform you are on.